# ProLiant DL320 G5p Server 2003 No longer boots

Tags: hp-proliant

I have the above server that runs a simple transcoder.

We wanted to upgrade the drive to 1TB from the 300s that are installed now.

I first wanted to clone the drive with clonezilla from the 300 to the 1TB and it really didn't see the drives as they are SAS and probably clonezilla doesn't like them?

I put back drive 2 (which was red and I'm not sure was actually working)

And things booted normally

I tried just plugging in the 1TB alone and was going to format and start from scratch with Server 2008 but it still didn't like what was happening.

I then put back the initial drive and it stopped booting.

The first error message is;

Failed or Degraded Volume Detected:
Volume (00:130) is currently in state INACTIVE/RESYNCING
Enter the LSI Logic Config Utility to investigate

then after attempting to start with the CD or NIC it gives the dreaded

Non-System disk or disk error
replace and strike any key when ready

and loops forever.

We had this years ago and I was able to put a floppy with fixmbr and repair the issue, however, none of the floppies on the server have anything that gives me the ability to fixmbr.   I tried HiRen's collection of fixmbr tools but none of them see the drive.

Is there anyway to bring the drives back to life?

Thanks

Comment: What does it say when you look at it in the lsi adapter setup?

Comment: You mixed and removed soo much your drive... When you tried the 1TB, you destroyed the old raid and configured that one a JBOD ? After you replug the 2 disk ?

Comment: Invoking SAS Configuration, then 2. enable SAS configuration

Comment: Invoking SAS Configuration, then 2. enable SAS configuration  Then goes into the configuration screen which shows.RAID properties and SAS Topology and under RAID it says INACTIVE RAID VOLUME but no second volume         Then under SAS it says First disk is Inactive and second disk is missing (but it is plugged in)  I clicked the Create Array but the first drive under drive status is ------- and the second drive says Wrg Type  The first drive gives size, but second is blank ----  But it does see both drives.  The same two that have been there forever DF300BABUF = 1 DF300BB6C3 = 2

Comment: Yes, I understand the LSI hates when you mix/match.  Is there anyway to get back to '0' and not have to format everything?  Right now everything is as it was originally when it was working.